# are these phrases correct?

Tags: repetition

I responded to **five** questions of my **five** colleagues, who arrived suddenly at my office then I solved two essentials crisis. 
I was exhausted all the day at work, however, I don't feel that I realize something at all.

Comment: The five questions from five colleagues - do you mean questions from five of your colleagues, or five from each of the five?

Comment: As implied by @exjoburger, the normal preposition here is ***from***, not ***of***.

Comment: every one of five colleagues asked one question. so the total of questions are five

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "two essentials crisis" should probably be "two important crises", although a crisis is usually important, so "solved two crises" would do. I'd even suggest "dealt with two major emergencies" instead. 
The last sentence should possibly end with "I don't feel that I accomplished anything".